# How to get client ip from request using symfony in docker

Tags: php, docker, symfony, ip

I try to get the ip using:

```
$request->getClientIp()
```

Which returns:

`172.30.0.1` instead of something like `210.110.98.180`

Using this something like this in docker-compose

```
http:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - "./:/var/www/http/"
    ports:
      - "80:80"
```

Comment: How does traffic reach to your container? via a proxy?

Comment: No, there's no proxy

Comment: What’s your docker network configuration?

Comment: it uses php:7.4-apache

Comment: @JeroendeBeer have managed to solve this problem?

Comment: @serj I'll post a solution

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it by adding it to a docker network.

```
http:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - "./:/var/www/http/"
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    networks:
      - bridge2

networks:
  bridge2:
    external: true
```